# Creating Shapely LineString from two Points

Tags: python, shapely

If have two points, from which I want to create a straight `LineString` object:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
A = Point(0,0)
B = Point(1,1)
```

The [Shapely manual for `LineString`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#linestrings) states:

> A sequence of `Point` instances is not a valid constructor parameter. A `LineString` is described by points, but is not composed of Point instances.

So if I have two points `A` and `B`, is there a shorter/better/easier way of creating a line `AB` than my current "best" guess...

```
AB = LineString(tuple(A.coords) + tuple(B.coords))
```

... which looks rather complicated. Is there an easier way?

---

With Shapely 1.3.2, the above statement from the manual is no longer correct. So from now on,

```
AB = LineString([A, B])
```

*works*!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since Shapely 1.3, you can create a LineString from Points:

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
>>> LineString([Point(0, 0), Point(1, 1)]).wkt
'LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1)'
```

Apologies for the contradiction in the manual.

Comment: On two machines (one Linux, one Windows), after upgrading to Shapely 1.3.1 (`shapely.__version__` agrees) and pasting your code verbatim, I receive a ValueError from linestring.pyc#228 about "Input `[<...Point object at 0x..>, <...Point object at 0x...>]` is the wrong shape for a LineString". Have I missed something?

Comment: Update: the corresponding [pull request #102](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/commit/f6e4e53b0f9a18b7e4959bdfaa85faa21f40b417) is only in master, not yet merged to branch 1.3 and thus not present in the current 1.3.1 release.

Comment: You're right. I've just now fixed this in https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/130 and uploaded 1.3.2 to PyPI.

Comment: Check, it works now; thanks (again) for the speedy followup!

Answer (score 6):

The base method is:

```
AB = LineString([(A.x,A.y), (B.x,B.y)])
```

You can also use slicing to concatenate the coordinate lists:

```
AB = LineString(A.coords[:] + B.coords[:])
```