# Turning GeoDataFrame of x,y coordinates into Linestrings using GROUPBY?

Tags: linestring, shapely, geopandas, points-to-line

I have a dataframe of X,Y coordinates that represent points along the paths taken by several different entities. Pseudo-data here, but it is roughly of the form:

```
entity_id   lat   lon   time

1001        34.5  14.2  4:55 pm
1001        34.7  14.5  4:58 pm
1001        35.0  14.6  5.03 pm

1002        27.1  19.2  2:01 pm
1002        27.4  19.3  2:08 pm
1002        27.4  19.9  2:09 pm
```

What I would like to do is group these points by `entity_id`, and then arrange the points sequentially in time to create a `LineString` object for each `entity_id`. The output will be several lines/paths, with each corresponding to an `entity_id`.

I can do this by looping through each `entity_id` and each point in `entity_id` and using the instructions provided [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95670/how-to-create-a-shapely-linestring-from-two-points), but is there a faster/more efficient way to do this leveraging GeoPandas or Shapely, perhaps with `groupby`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think I found an interim solution, which I'm posting in case it's useful for anyone:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

# Zip the coordinates into a point object and convert to a GeoDataFrame
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.lon, df.lat)]
df = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)

# Aggregate these points with the GroupBy
df = df.groupby(['entity_id'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist()))
df = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')
```

Note that if you have single-point trajectories in your data, you will have to discard these first or LineString will throw an error.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530568/can-pandas-groupby-aggregate-into-a-list-rather-than-sum-mean-etc) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby) post were helpful in writing the GroupBy function.

---

**Update**: If you didn't discard the single point, you can also use the conditional sentence like:

```
 df = df.groupby(['entity_id'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist()) if x.size > 1 else x.tolist())
```

Comment: that is amazing!

Comment: In case you only want the grouped dataset and to keep ID as a column, this should help: `df.groupby('entity_id', as_index=False).agg({'geometry': lambda x: ...})`

Comment: You can actually condense the first two commands (zip and gdf creation) into one: `df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(df.x, df.y))`