# How to create a linestring from a geopandas data frame?

Tags: python, geopandas, linestring

I am trying to create a linestring from a geopandas dataframe with points as geometries

```
date_time   latitude    longitude   year    data01  hour    minute  data02
0   2019-11-08 08:21:38 36.830444   -2.466583   2019    312 8   21  0
1   2019-11-08 08:32:15 36.830250   -2.466611   2019    312 8   32  0
2   2019-11-08 08:41:51 36.830417   -2.466778   2019    312 8   41  0
3   2019-11-08 08:51:53 36.830361   -2.466833   2019    312 8   51  0
4   2019-11-08 09:01:50 36.830528   -2.466806   2019    312 9   1   0
```

using the this code:

```
    date_time   latitude    longitude   year    data01  hour    minute  data02  geometry
0   2019-11-08 08:21:38 36.830444   -2.466583   2019    312 8   21  0   POINT (-2.466583 36.830444)
1   2019-11-08 08:32:15 36.830250   -2.466611   2019    312 8   32  0   POINT (-2.466611 36.83025)
2   2019-11-08 08:41:51 36.830417   -2.466778   2019    312 8   41  0   POINT (-2.466778 36.830417)
3   2019-11-08 08:51:53 36.830361   -2.466833   2019    312 8   51  0   POINT (-2.466833 36.830361)
4   2019-11-08 09:01:50 36.830528   -2.466806   2019    312 9   1   0   POINT (-2.466806 36.830528)

geo_df = geo_df.groupby(['date_time'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist()))
geo_df = GeoDataFrame(geo_df, geometry='geometry')
```

Error: ValueError: LineStrings must have at least 2 coordinate tuples

How can I do that ? or can I create the linestring using just the latitude and longitude columns?

Even if use geopandas to convert to linestring geometry the columns look no good for that

```
geometry = [LineString(xy) for xy in zip(df.longitude, df.latitude)]
geo_df = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)
geo_df

 ValueError: Input (-2.466583, 36.830444) is the wrong shape for a LineString
```

Answer (score 4):

With all your solutions, you try to create a LineString with only one point

Since all the dates (hours) are different:

```
geo_df = geo_df.groupby(['date_time'])
print("number of groups:", geo_df.ngroups)
number of groups: 5 # and 5 original geometries
for group in gdf.groupby(['date_time']).geometry:
    print(group)
(Timestamp('2019-11-08 08:21:38'), 0    POINT (-2.466583 36.830444)
 Name: geometry, dtype: object)
(Timestamp('2019-11-08 08:32:15'), 1    POINT (-2.466611 36.83025)
Name: geometry, dtype: object)
(Timestamp('2019-11-08 08:41:51'), 2    POINT (-2.466778 36.830417)
Name: geometry, dtype: object)
(Timestamp('2019-11-08 08:51:53'), 3    POINT (-2.466833 36.830361)
Name: geometry, dtype: object)
(Timestamp('2019-11-08 09:01:50'), 4    POINT (-2.466806 36.830528)
Name: geometry, dtype: object)
```

*Only one point per group -> Error: ValueError: LineStrings must have at least 2 coordinate tuples)*

And

```
geometry = [xy for xy in zip(df.longitude, df.latitude)]
print(geometry)
[(-2.466583, 36.830444), (-2.466611, 36.83025), (-2.4667779999999997, 36.830417), (-2.4668330000000003, 36.830360999999996), (-2.466806, 36.830528)
# geometry is a list of point coordinates
Point(geometry[0]).wkt
'POINT (-2.466583 36.830444)'
#but
LineString(geometry[0])
...
```

*ValueError: Input (-2.466583, 36.830444) is the wrong shape for a LineString*

**And I suppose you want to create a line with all the points, therefore**

```
 print(LineString(geometry).wkt)
 LINESTRING (-2.466583 36.830444, -2.466611 36.83025, -2.466778 36.830417, -2.466833 36.830361, -2.466806 36.830528)
```

or directly

```
print(LineString(df.geometry).wkt)
LINESTRING (-2.466583 36.830444, -2.466611 36.83025, -2.466778 36.830417, -2.466833 36.830361, -2.466806 36.830528)
```

If you want to use groupby to create separate lines choose another column to regroup  (look at [Turning GeoDataFrame of x,y coordinates into Linestrings using GROUPBY?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202190/turning-geodataframe-of-x-y-coordinates-into-linestrings-using-groupby) or [Convert Points to Lines Geopandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071365/convert-points-to-lines-geopandas))

with data02 modified (2 groups, 0 and 1)

```
date_time,latitude,longitude,year,data01,hour,minute,data02,wtkcolumn
2019-11-08 08:21:38,36.830444,-2.466583,   2019,    312, 8 ,  21 , 0 ,  POINT (-2.466583 36.830444)
2019-11-08 08:32:15,36.830250,-2.466611,   2019,    312, 8  , 32,  0,   POINT (-2.466611 36.83025)
2019-11-08 08:41:51 ,36.830417,-2.466778,   2019,    312, 8 ,  41 , 1 ,  POINT (-2.466778 36.830417)
2019-11-08 08:51:53 ,36.830361,-2.466833,   2019,    312, 8,   51,  1 ,  POINT (-2.466833 36.830361)
2019-11-08 09:01:50, 36.830528, -2.466806,   2019,    312, 9 ,  1  , 1,   POINT (-2.466806 36.830528)

list(geo_df.groupby(['data02'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist())))
[<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x11bc81668>, <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x11bc81400>]
```

Comment: For more on creating spatial objects you might look here https://pygis.io/docs/e_new_vectors.html