# Creating LineString and length of LineString from multiple latlon points for each row in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapely, pandas

So I want to create a LineString and get the length of the LineString from two sets of LatLon coordinates (points)  in each row in a Pandas Dataframe, and store in a new column

> [image: Blockquote]

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95670/how-to-create-a-shapely-linestring-from-two-points would seem to answer the question/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` to create the output column like this:

```
import shapely.geometry as geom
your_df['geometry'] = your_df.apply(lambda x: geom.LineString([(x['startlat'], x['startlon']) , (x['endlat'], x['endlon'])]), axis = 1)
```

If your coordinates columns aren't float make sure to parse them first with `float(...)`