# Converting GPS track to MultiLineString using GeoPandas and shapely

Tags: python, gps, geopandas, shapely, tracking

I have many GPS tracks (long, lat, alt, timestamp) from heavy trucks. Trucks are go on some paths. How can I extract the path from GPS tracks without deviation and convert it to one MultiLineString?

[image: Raw Data]

I found Cushen [five steps advice based on PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/387297/191178).

I have done  steps 1 (get clusters) and 2 (get centers):

[image: Kmeans]

But I don't know how do step 3 "generate a line that connects each cluster centre point"?

How can I connect these points to a MultiLineString using GeoPandas?

Comment: With the timestamp you could add the points in order to a multilinestring? Sort the points in an array by timestamp and then in a for loop add to a linestring as described here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95670/creating-shapely-linestring-from-two-points

Comment: I have multiple tracks with gps deviation on the same roads. The problem is to remove deviation. At first step  I use KMeans clusterisation and loose timestamps.

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question. Instead [Edit] the question to contain the clarification.

Comment: You can surely keep the indexes of the source points after the clustering and join the timestamps again

Comment: Can you share your data

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have a column for the unique `truck_id` and a `time` variable.
Sort the gdf by time so the sequence of the points is correct.
Then you can use `groupby` and `agg` method to make a list of points for each route.

Then use `apply` and `LineString` for converting list of points to lines:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

gdf = gdf.sort_values('time').reset_index(dtopr=True)

gdf_grouped = gdf.groupby(['truck_id']).agg({'geometry':list})

gdf_grouped['geometry'] = gdf_grouped['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x))

gdf_grouped = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf_grouped)
```

If you are expecting any break for a truck (two routes with same `truck_id`) then you need to find a way to get a unique `route_id` instead.